# SPFX: Custom action to move bulk document from one library to another and adding metadata to these files

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, visual-web-part, pnp, react

My scenario: I need to be able to bulk move files from one library to another and also bulk add metadata to those newly move files.

I thinking of creating an spfx/react application or any method is welcome

Comment: How many files you're expecting to move? Are libraries at the same site collection or not?

Comment: There is no definte number of files,it varies. Users need an app so that they can move files with metadata between libraries in the same site collection

Comment: You're basically asking about making a browser-based migration utility. You're going to have scaling issues. This is why Sergei asked about how many documents.

Comment: Also, are you expecting version history and item level security to also come along for the ride?

Comment: The scenario here is users will be just moving files from one project folder to another in a second list. so it depend from 5-25 files for one transfer. version history is great if we cacn keep it but not mandatory. NO for item level security

Comment: I do think it should be like a sharepoint framework extensions